# Determining $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is a diagonal matrix without knowing $A$ but only its eigenvalues and two eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I'm studying for a linear algebra exam and there is an exercise (about diagonalizable matrices) that I don't know how to resolve.

> $M$ is a diagonalizable matrix such that $$\det(M-\lambda I4) = (-2-\lambda)(-2-\lambda)(3-\lambda)(4-\lambda)$$
>
> where
>
> $$
> M
>     \begin{bmatrix}
>     1\\
>     2\\
>     0\\
>     3\\
>     \end{bmatrix}
> =
> \begin{bmatrix}
>     4\\
>     8\\
>     0\\
>     12\\
>     \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>
> $$
> VM(-2) = 
> \begin{bmatrix}
>     2y\\
>     y\\
>     -w\\
>     w\\
>     \end{bmatrix}
> : (y,w) \neq (0,0)
> $$
>
> $$
> VM(3) = 
> \begin{bmatrix}
>     0\\
>     y\\
>     2y\\
>     -y\\
>     \end{bmatrix}
> : (y) \neq 0
> $$
>
> Build a matrix $P$ so that $P^{-1}MP = \mathrm{diag}(4; -3; 3; -2)$.

It’s my first question here so sorry for my pour formation. I really need to know how to do this. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If $P^{-1}AP$ is diagonal if and only if the columns of $P$ are eigenvectors of $A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first piece of information tells us that $(1,2,0,3)^T$ is an eigenvector of $M$ with eigenvalue $4$.

From your second piece of information, you can deduce that $(2,1,0,0)^T$ and $(0,0,-1,1)^T$ are eigenvectors of $M$ with eigenvalue $2$. They are clearly linearly independent.

From your third piece of information, it follows that $(0,1,2,-1)^T$ is an eigenvector of $M$ with eigenvalue $3$.

So, take$$M=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&0&0\\2&1&0&1\\0&0&1&2\\3&0&1&-1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Oh, I knew about your second and third point, but I didn't know about the first one. Can you explain me how/why I can take that conclusion from my first piece of information? Thank you, your answer helped me a lot.

Comment: Your first piece of information is that$$M.(1,2,0,3)^T=(4,8,0,12)^T=4\times(1,2,0,3)^T.$$

Comment: I see it now. Thank you! Now I can proceed with my studies... :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.